# change customer email address in ubercart

Tags: 6, ubercart

Is it possible to to change customer's email address in already created order? I have some customers who type wrong email address and complain that they did not receive any email... I tried to change it in customer's info but new email is not reflected in already created order. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1904502) with ubercart. The only way to change it, currently, is to find the order in the uc_orders table, and to update the primary_email field in the record.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - 
go to users account, change email address, this will not be reflected in orders. You go to the order edit page, section customer info, search for existing customer, put corrected email address, system will find new address and you can use it.